# How to be notified when the user clicks in the tableview below the last row?

Tags: qt, qtableview

When the user clicks in a tableview on a row, the events (clicked, activated, pressed, etc) are fired. So far so good.
When the user clicks below the last row (when the tableview is bigger than required to display all the rows) I don't know how to be notified:
the selectionModel()->currentChanged() is not fired.
Visually, the currentRow seems to lose the focus, but at this time the tableView->currentIndex() indicates the last clicked row.

Comment: You can try to use `QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged` signal. Or you can install an event filter on the view's `viewport()` and intercept every mouse click.

Comment: Thank you, the selectionChanged signal does the trick.